# Measurement of the $(|x_0\rangle + |x_1\rangle)$ state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements

We know that, in a quantum-mechanical system, for every pure state, there always exists a measurement whose outcome is known. How would you physically describe a a position measurement of the state $(|x_0\rangle + |x_1\rangle)$? It is an eigenvector of the operator which is non-diagonal in the position basis, and I don't really know how to imagine such an experiment.

Comment: Well, it has eigenvalue 0 under the operator $\hat{x}-|x_0\rangle x_0\langle x_0| -|x_1\rangle x_1\langle x_1| $.

Comment: This I understand. But how would you organize such an measurement?

Comment: How do you measure |x>?

Comment: The beam of particles is entering the target made of small pixels-detectors. Each of those produces an electric signal when a particle hits it.

Comment: ***And*** all other pixels are inert/quiet, otherwise you are measuring all states containing an |x> component. So try an $x_0,x_1$ coincidence circuit with anti coincidence on *all* other pixels. It should yield a 1 for this state and a 0 for all others.

Comment: Let me ask then a stupid question: in those first double-slit experiments which people performed 100yrs ago, did it happen so that a single emitted electron/photon was producing the multiple "pixel" activation? What I've learned in school is that in those experiments the particles hits the screen at a definite position, while the quantum-mechanical nature of the experiment follows from the distribution on the screen.

Comment: No, these were incoherent measurements with no coincidence. They projected the wavefunction, without measuring direct interference--decohered or projected the electron on a single pixel/grain. They measured probability for an electron to be in $x_1$ or $x_0$ in your language. They did not contrast, e.g., $|x_0\rangle \pm |x_1\rangle$ to each other . The pattern that emerged for many such electrons reflected the probability. Modern electrons split/duplicate the photon and measure coincidences and interference.

Comment: Rather than spending effort on an infinite-dim Hilbert space, you might reinterpret $x_0,x_1$ as the locations of 2 electron detectors in a Stern-Gerlach experiment. You are then asking about observation of the state $|\uparrow \rangle+| \downarrow \rangle$. Maybe recasting your question in these terms might make it clearer.

Comment: Hah, this example is too simple. Clearly it's just the $S_x$ eigenstate. The spin measurement is a rare case when for every pure state it's clear which observable to pick (and perform a realistic experiment).